# How to delete rows in a tensor with tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

For example, I have :

`X=tf.constant([9,5,3,7,2,4,7,8,1])`

And I would like to delete all the values greater than 5 :
`Y=tf.constant([3,2,4,1])`

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the tensorflow [`boolean_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) operation:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5])
b = tf.boolean_mask(a,tf.greater(5,a))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(b)) #[1,2,3,4]
```