# Is there a tensorflow analog to numpy.delete?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Is there an analog to [`numpy.delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) where I could just delete a row or column from a 2-mode tensor?

Unlike the following answers that filter by the content of the array

- [Removing certain rows from tensor in tensorflow without using tf.RaggedTensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820951/removing-certain-rows-from-tensor-in-tensorflow-without-using-tf-raggedtensor)
- [How to delete rows in a tensor with tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588043/how-to-delete-rows-in-a-tensor-with-tensorflow)

I want to simply delete certain rows and columns by providing indices.

Comment: There's nothing sophisticated about `np.delete`.  It's pure Python which you can read.  If it seems long it's because it tries to handle many different cases and dimensions.  In some cases it just copies a couple of slices to a new target array.  Or concatenates slices.  In others it constructs a `mask` of items you want to keep.  `delete` is really just make a new array with selected blocks/rows/columns from the original.